# Megamenu dropdown menus doesn't work in IE8 or lower IE

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, megamenu

Hy, i'm using a megamenu based on this one http://geedmo.github.io/yamm/ and i just can't make the dropdown work to IE8.

Comment: What goes wrong if you try? Do you get errors? Is Yamm supposed to work on IE8 anyway? If so, does that Yamm homepage that you link to work in IE8? If it does, what are the differences between your site and the Yamm homepage? Have you checked all its features on caniuse.com? Where is your site?

Comment: There are no errors and the yamm page with the example megamenu doesn't work either on IE8, the difference it's only instead of click opens with hover and some colors. I can't provide you my site sorry

Comment: (I add the display:block; it was missing):                                                                             .dropdown-menu li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu li > a:focus, .dropdown-submenu:hover > a {
  color: #a7a7a7;
  display: block;
}                                                                                (add overflow:visible to .navbar-collapse.collapse):
.nav-collapse.collapse {
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}                                                                                Thanks for trying to help me

Comment: have you resolved it???

Answer (score 0):

Only some CSS3 properties and HTML5 elements that Bootstrap use (and by association, Yamm) are supported by Internet Explorer 8 and 9. Internet Explorer 8 requires the use of [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to enable media query support. There is information about [browser support on the Bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-ie9). I've successfully got [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-ie9) and [Yamm](http://geedmo.github.io/yamm/) working in IE8 but needed to add respond.js and a [html5 shim hack](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv) in to work.

```
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

> **Internet Explorer 8 and Respond.js**
>
> Beware of the following caveats when using Respond.js in your development and production environments for Internet Explorer 8.
>   Respond.js and cross-domain CSS
>
> Using Respond.js with CSS hosted on a different (sub)domain (for example, on a CDN) requires some additional setup. See the Respond.js docs for details.
>   Respond.js and file://
>
> Due to browser security rules, Respond.js doesn't work with pages viewed via the file:// protocol (like when opening a local HTML file). To test responsive features in IE8, view your pages over HTTP(S). See the Respond.js docs for details.
>   Respond.js and @import
>
> Respond.js doesn't work with CSS that's referenced via @import. In particular, some Drupal configurations are known to use @import. See the Respond.js docs for details.
>   Internet Explorer 8 and box-sizing
>
> IE8 does not fully support box-sizing: border-box; when combined with min-width, max-width, min-height, or max-height. For that reason, as of v3.0.1, we no longer use max-width on .containers.